# "".constructor vs 2.constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, constructor, numbers, primitive-types

I've just been experimenting with a little bit of Javascript and got to the point of understanding the inheritance concept.

I am able to get an evaluation for the below code:

```
"".constructor
//which evaluates to function String()
```

Ok Cool. But why is it that when I do the below code, there is an error?

```
2.constructor
//returns an error
```

Basically both are primitives right?, so should there not be an error for the empty string as well?

Hope someone can give me a good explanation that will help me learn this one better. Looking forward to your support.

Comment: (2).constructor => function Number() ... (Avoids parsing ambiguity for floats with a decimal)

Comment: @Alex K - omg it worked! Well yeah didn't think of the parens for this one. I guess I will place them next time that I am going to try to do this. God bless and thanks. Finally evaluated to (2).constructor ==> function Number()

Answer (score 1):

You could spend another dot for the decimal point.

```js
console.log(2..toString());
console.log(2.2.toString());
```

Or wrap the value in parenthesis.

```js
console.log((2).toString());
console.log((2.2).toString());
```

Comment: Yes, Nina thank you. The paren idea given by @Alex K worked. But yeah appreciate your support.